# API сбербанк, смотреть список переводов?

Tags: python, node.js

Мне нужен API сбербанка по типу API qiwi или yoomoney, есть ли подобные библиотеки или официальные API, конкретно меня интересует список последних, допустим, 50 переводов по карте

Приветствуются любые костыли и использование внутреннего api

Желательно на nodejs либо python

Comment: А в чём проблема? [Sber api](https://api.developer.sber.ru/), [Python SDK](https://developers.sber.ru/docs/ru/sberid/sdk/pythonsdk/overview)